# Using browserify-shim to browserify Foundation for apps

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, browserify, browserify-shim

I've been trying to user browserify with Foundation for apps, which was recently added on npm (version 1.02). Since the npm package from foundation-apps is not commonjs compatible I've decided to use `"browserify-shim"`

The difference between the bower component and npm package of foundation for apps, is that the former comes with all the dependencies included (angular, ui.router, angular-animate etc), while the npm version comes only with the absolutely necessary stuff (foundation core, components and services).

I installed angular and angular-animate from npm, and shimmed them (npm versions of angular/angular-animate are also not in the commonjs format). As for ui.router, the npm package supports commonJS, so no need for shiming.

[This is my package.json](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2c37f3973a9bbd1bafc2)

[and this is my main.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10e0c619d7461ec1aa4a) (app entry point)

Browserify successfully creates a bundle.js file, that includes everything (foundation.core, components, services as well as angular, angular-ui-router and angular-animate)
But my app instantiation fails with this message:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module application due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module foundation.dynamicRouting due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'foundation.dynamicRouting' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/nomod?p0=foundation.dynamicRouting
```

Any ideas what might be the case? I'm suspecting there's a dependency somewhere that didn't catch my attention, or perhaps something I messed up in [package.json](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2c37f3973a9bbd1bafc2)